# Word for 1, 2, 3 ordinal number

Tags: word-request

For example,

3=collective

1, 1, 1=individual

Then,

1, 2, 3= ???

What word (adjective) expresses 1, 2, 3?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you say "3" is "collective"? Is it just that *3 = **three** [things]* is a PLURAL noun, whereas *1 = **one** [thing]* is SINGULAR? There are many adjectives that could describe "1, 2, 3" - including ***sequential***.

Comment: @nonameeee I think you mean cardinal number, not ordinal.

Comment: Is there a word or concept in your native language that you are trying to translate?  It might help if we knew what that was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean numbers that just appear in a sequence then they are 'sequential'; however, given your other examples, I believe the word you are looking for is *cumulative*.

'Cumulative' means *the total so far*, the *running total*. I presume this is what you mean based on the fact that you say "3" is the 'collective' (I would say 'total'), the three '1's are the individuals being counted, so the increasing total of 1,2, and finally 3 sounds like *cumulative total*.

Comment: They could also be asking for the term "Prime Powers". I don't think it's useful to guess. It would be better to encourage the author to clarify their meaning.

Comment: @ColleenV I can imagine it is quite difficult for an English learner, who is looking for a word they don't know, to describe it. They have done so with examples, and I think my answer is a little more than a wild guess. I've updated it to present options rather than be dogmatic about the meaning, and I'm hoping they can either confirm or clarify, in which case I'll be happy to update.

Comment: We can ask learners to explain a bit more without demanding that they provide us with perfectly grammatical answers to our questions. If we can understand what they're asking better, we can help them improve their question, which will make people more likely to up-vote it and more likely to answer it. Giving them a guess instead of an answer is at odds with the purpose of ELL, because your guess, even if it is correct, doesn't help anyone else because the question is so vague.